# Матрац: це або він?

Tags: займенники

Матрац як чоловічій рід, може відмінюватися як (він), чи тільки як (це)? (Він)- дана форма застосовується до живих та не живих предметів? 
Тобто чи правильно буде запитати  "Він без пружин" чи "Воно без пружин?

Comment: "Неживість" матраца проявляється в тому, що він *відмінюється* як неістота, тобто як "що", а не "хто".  В знахідному відмінку (кого? що?): знайшли (що?) матрац, а не (кого?) матраца.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Слово «[матра́ц](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=50141&page=1583)» (до речі, за словниками це слово пишеться саме так, хоча варіант «матра́с» теж іноді вживається) в українській мові **чоловічого роду**. В українській мові іменники на позначення неживих предметів часто бувають чоловічого чи жіночого роду — тут немає нічого дивного.

Відповідно: «м*ій* матрац», «нов*ий* матрац», «матрац лежа*в*», «ц*ей* матрац», «т*ой* матрац», «в*ін* без пружин».
А не: «м*оє* матрац», «нов*е* матрац», «матрац лежа*ло*».

Утім:

- Не заборонено вживати слово «матрац» зі словами «[це](http://sum.in.ua/s/ce)» і «[то](http://sum.in.ua/s/to)» — просто вони тоді виконуватимуть іншу функцію. Наприклад: «це — мій новий матрац», «пружинний матрац — це матрац, що містить пружини» тощо. Рід іменника тут не завада, **частки** «це» і «то» можна вживати з іменниками будь-яких родів (наприклад, «це — моя наречена», «оптимістка — це жінка, яка, перебуваючи між двома неприємностями, завжди загадує бажання»).
- До матраца **іноді** можна застосувати й займенник «[воно́](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=15848&page=525)». Передумови тут такі:

  1. «Воно» в розмовному стилі можуть застосовувати заміть «він» чи «вона», особливо з нотками зневаги чи пестливості. Наприклад (про людину): «Втомилося воно… То, може, хай іде до біса, якщо таке кволе?» Відповідно, можна уявити, як покупець у крамниці питає консультанта про певний матрац сумнівного вигляду: «Воно точно хоча б один рік мені послугує? Не доведеться його вже через місяць виносити на смітник?»
  2. «Воно», загалом, — нейтральний займенник на позначення предмету невизначеного роду. Припустімо, якщо Ви ще не вирішили, як назвати предмент, що перед Вами (наприклад, «матрац» чи «перина» чи якось ще), чи забули, як він називається, Вам просто доведеться назвати його «воно».